# Efficient way to multiply each elements of numpy 1d array and 3d Array

Tags: python, numpy

I want to multiply each elements of 1dArray and each matrices of 3dArray without `for` loop.

```
arr1d2=np.array([1,2])
arr3d222=np.array([[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]]])

# Correct Solution is below
for i1 in range(len(arr1d2)):
    print(arr1d2[i1]*arr3d222[i1])
```

I try to find more efficient way to do this. I suppose that this `for` loop is the bottleneck of my code.

Attempt:

```
print(arr1d2[:]*arr3d222[:])
```

Thanks for any help.

## Time Comparision of Answers

```
import time
import numpy as np
dim=250
arr1d=np.arange(dim)

arr3d,val_arr3=np.zeros([dim,dim,dim]),1
result=np.zeros(np.shape(arr3d))
for i1 in range(len(arr3d)):
  for i2 in range(len(arr3d[0])):
    for i3 in range(len(arr3d[0,0])):
        arr3d[i1,i2,i3]=val_arr3
        val_arr3=val_arr3+1

start_time1 = time.time()
# Correct Solution
for i1 in range(dim):
    result[i1]=arr1d[i1]*arr3d[i1]  
print("Method 1 : For Loop\n%s seconds." % (time.time() - start_time1))

result=np.zeros(np.shape(arr3d))
start_time2 = time.time()
result=arr1d.reshape(len(arr3d),1,1) * arr3d
print("Method 2 : arr1d.reshape(len(arr3d),1,1) * arr3d \n%s seconds." % (time.time() - start_time2))

result=np.zeros(np.shape(arr3d))
start_time3 = time.time()
result=arr1d[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis] * arr3d
print("Method 3 : arr1d[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis] * arr3d \n%s seconds." % (time.time() - start_time3))
```

Result is

```
Method 1 : For Loop
0.06770634651184082 seconds.
Method 2 : arr1d.reshape(len(arr3d),1,1) * arr3d 
0.05272269248962402 seconds.
Method 3 : arr1d[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis] * arr3d 
0.048714399337768555 seconds.
```

Comment: Do you want to do matrix multiplication?  Or, do you want the first element of your first array to multiply against each of the first elements of the second array.  And second element of first array multiplied against each second element of the lists in second array?  Returned as a sum or as the product of the multiplications?

Comment: I want to multiply first element of 1dArray and whole elements of the first element of 3dArray which is matrix. I mean `result[0]=1*[[1,2],[3,4]]` and `result[1]=2*[[5,6],[7,8]]`. It should return 3dArray.

Comment: Your `correct solution` loop doesn't accumulate values; it throws each `A` away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `np.newaxis` so that the number of dimensions match:

```
arr1d2[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis] * arr3d222
```

Comment: Thank you mikewatt and @emre for editing the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just get the first array to the right shape:

```
arr1d2.reshape(len(arr3d222),1,1) * arr3d222
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this method is slower than `for` loop. `for` Loop : `1.52587890625e-05` seconds. Method 2 : `arr1d2.reshape(len(arr3d222),1,1) * arr3d222` `2.09808349609375e-05` seconds.

Comment: Can you share how to do the comparison? Mine is this:

`In [193]: %%timeit
     ...: k = np.empty(0)
     ...: for i1 in range(len(arr1d2)):
     ...:     k = np.append(k,arr1d2[i1]*arr3d222[i1])`

20.2 µs ± 167 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

`In [194]: %timeit arr1d2.reshape(len(arr3d222),1,1) * arr3d222`

3.22 µs ± 11.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

Comment: By the way, the method 3 does not give the correct result unless it becomes: `arr1d2[:, np.newaxis,np.newaxis] * arr3d222`

Comment: Also, -maybe it is not important- I think your timing calculation for the method 1 is not realistic because `A=arr1d[i1]*arr3d[i1]` does not give the final result that includes the entire array.